# Compile BulletPhysics with double precision in 64-bit for Windows

Tags: visual-studio, cmake, 64-bit, bullet, bulletphysics

I am trying to create a 64-bit windows build of Bullet Physics, with double precision enabled.

If I use the provided VS2010 project, I can build Bullet Physics in 64-bit, but if I try to #define BT_USE_DOUBLE_PRECISION, i get tons of build errors.

If I use CMake to generate a new project, I can easily enable double precision in CMakeLists.txt, but I could not find a way to get it to generate a project that builds x64.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is probably obvious to anyone with some CMake experience, but I finally found it out:

```
cmake -G "Visual Studio 11 Win64"
```

This will lead CMake to generate a proper 64bit build config for the project.

Comment: Can you please further explain what went wrong and why this fixes the issue?

Comment: Better, or still something missing? What?